# Generics in kotlin. How to pass implementation of Abstract class with generics

Tags: generics, kotlin, syntax, architecture

I am struggling with generics / interfaces / implementation in kotlin.

The question is why I cannot to pass a implementation to **HabitsRepository** like this:

```
class HabitsRepository(habitDao: HabitDao, habitConverter: HabitConverter) :
    AbstractRepository<AbstractDataSource<AbstractEntity>, AbstractConverter<AbstractModel, AbstractEntity>>(
        habitDao,
        habitConverter
    )
```

I got following error

[image]

My setup is following:

**HabitsRepository**

```
 class HabitsRepository(habitDao: HabitDao, habitConverter: HabitConverter) :
    AbstractRepository<AbstractDataSource<AbstractEntity>, AbstractConverter<AbstractModel, AbstractEntity>>(
        habitDao as AbstractDataSource<AbstractEntity>,
        habitConverter as AbstractConverter<AbstractModel, AbstractEntity>
    )
```

**HabitDao**

```
@Dao
interface HabitDao : AbstractDataSource<Habit>{

    @Query("SELECT * FROM habit WHERE id=:id ")
    override fun getById(id: String): Single<Habit>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM habit")
    override fun getAll(): Single<List<Habit>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    override fun insert(entity: AbstractEntity): Completable

    @Delete
    override fun delete(habit: AbstractEntity) : Completable

    @Update
    override fun update(habit: AbstractEntity): Completable
}
```

**HabitConverter**

```
class HabitConverter : AbstractConverter<HabitModel, Habit> {
    override fun toModel(entity: Habit): HabitModel {
        return HabitModel()
    }

    override fun toEntity(model: HabitModel): Habit {
        return Habit()
    }
}
```

**HabitDatabaseSource**

```
class HabitDatabaseSource @VisibleForTesting constructor(private val habitDao: HabitDao) : HabitDao {

    override fun getById(id: String): Single<Habit> = habitDao.getById(id)

    override fun getAll(): Single<List<Habit>> = habitDao.getAll()

    override fun insert(entity: AbstractEntity): Completable = habitDao.insert(entity)

    override fun delete(habit: AbstractEntity): Completable = habitDao.delete(habit)

    override fun update(habit: AbstractEntity): Completable = habitDao.update(habit)
}
```

**AbstractDataSource**

```
interface AbstractDataSource<T : AbstractEntity> {
    fun getById(id: String): Single<T>
    fun getAll(): Single<List<T>>
    fun insert(entity: AbstractEntity): Completable
    fun delete(entity: AbstractEntity): Completable
    fun update(entity: AbstractEntity): Completable
}
```

**AbstractEntity** / **AbstractModel**

```
abstract class AbstractEntity
abstract class AbstractModel
```

**AbstractConverter**

```
interface AbstractConverter<AM: AbstractModel, AE: AbstractEntity>{
    fun toModel(entity: AE) : AM
    fun toEntity(model: AM): AE
}
```

**AbstractRepository**

```
abstract class AbstractRepository<ADS: AbstractDataSource<AbstractEntity>, AC: AbstractConverter<AbstractModel, AbstractEntity>>(
    private val abstractDataSource: ADS,
    private val abstractConverter: AC
){
    fun getById(id: String): Single<AbstractModel> {
        return abstractDataSource.getById(id).map { abstractConverter.toModel(it) }
    }

    fun getAll(): Single<MutableList<AbstractModel>> =
        abstractDataSource.getAll().flattenAsObservable {it}.map { abstractConverter.toModel(it) }.toList()

    fun insert(model: AbstractModel): Completable = abstractDataSource.insert(abstractConverter.toEntity(model))

    fun delete(model: AbstractModel): Completable = abstractDataSource.delete(abstractConverter.toEntity(model))

    fun update(model: AbstractModel): Completable = abstractDataSource.update(abstractConverter.toEntity(model))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HabitDao` is not an `AbstractDataSource<AbstractEntity>`. It is defined as `AbstractDataSource<Habit>`. When a generic type is not defined as `in` or `out`, then it is *invariant*, meaning you must pass a parameter with the exact type, not a supertype or subtype. There is a similar issue for your `HabitConverter` and both of its superclass's generic types.

And taking it even a step farther, your `HabitDao` is a subclass of `AbstractDataSource` so you are breaking invariance at two levels.

Your `HabitRepository` must declare the exact types of the Habit classes it is using:

```
class HabitsRepository(habitDao: HabitDao, habitConverter: HabitConverter) :
    AbstractRepository<HabitDao, HabitConverter>(
        habitDao,
        habitConverter
    )
```

At least with your `AbstractRepository`, the generic types only occur in producing positions, so you could declare their types as `out` without losing any functionality:

```
abstract class AbstractRepository<out ADS: AbstractDataSource<AbstractEntity>, out AC: AbstractConverter<AbstractModel, AbstractEntity>> ( //...
```

and then you could be less strict in your `HabitsRepository` definition:

```
class HabitsRepository(habitDao: HabitDao, habitConverter: HabitConverter) :
    AbstractRepository<AbstractDataSource<Habit>, AbstractConverter<HabitModel, Habit>>(
        habitDao,
        habitConverter
    )
```

But `AbstractDataSource` and `AbstractConverter` are both producers and consumers of their generic types, so their types have to be invariant.